# HTML Button background-color property does not work

Tags: html, css

In the following [page](https://code4projects.net):

I have a gray button (see the section with first book, it is the only gray button of the page) but it is expected to be a blue one. I cut&paste the code from a Mail service (see below).
The property:
background-color: #47abd5;
does not work. Why?

```html
<style>
    #mlb2-3734193 button.ml-subscribe-button {
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: Open Sans!important;
        font-size: 24px !important;
        height: 60px;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: #47abd5;
        color: #ffffff!important;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 0px 24px;
    }
</style>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&   subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<form id="mlb2-3734193" action="//app.mailerlite.com/webforms/popup/z0d1n7" data-code="z0d1n7" data-id="243593" target="_blank">
    <div stylclass="button-preview">
        <button style="background-color: #47abd5;" type="submit" class="ml-subscribe-button">Iscriviti</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.mailerlite.com/js/w/button.min.js?veb3acdd46bf692c067c6a9fe9fbc07d6"></script>
```

Comment: You have a gradient applied to the button in styles.css using `background: gradient code`. Change your `background-color: #47abd5;` to `background: #47abd5;` and it will override the gradient.

Comment: It works to me with the same code: [Image of the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d54fi.png) It may be the explorer you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of this css being applied to your button.

```
a.button,
button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #dfdfdf, #ffffff);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #dfdfdf 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #dfdfdf);
}
```

There is a background gradient which is overwriting your styles I suppose.
As @Turnip suggests change it to background instead of background-colour and it will work

Comment: This isn't technically "overwriting" OPs `background-color`. It is applying a `background-image` which sits _on top of_ the `background-color`

Comment: This is nice in-depth detail to know

Comment: where is your Gray button,for me i can just see the blue ,can you add a screen shot

Comment: Can you help me to understand how you get the stylesheet that overwrite my setting. Sorry if I ask this but I am not a CSS expert and I want in future solve issues like this by myself.

Comment: Can you also help me to center it and make it more similar to other buttons of the page?

Comment: Create file mystyles.css, include reference in your html file <head> section
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pathtoyourfile/mystyles.css">
Make sure it is last css file included in your <head> as css is applied to whatsoever later included or more specific.

Press F12 in your web browser, find element you want to override, copy its selector, paste it in your style file, make amends. It's quite complicated to explain it all for someone who might be just starting, I suggest you reading css guides on w3school

Comment: If you want to center it set parrent containers style to text-align: center; or the button style to be display: block; margin: auto;

Comment: Ok it worked. I copied the same button also in the section where is the video. Even if the code is the same the blue seems more light. Why? I also tried to make the two button more similar to the button with the italian word "Avvisami". The gradient should go from #47abd5 to #2e97c4 and the code I cut&paste from my mail service is here at the botto of this comment. How can change it to have the right gradient? I think you are able to check my current code I cut&paste from Mail service (MailerLite).

Answer (score 5):

remove background-color property just use background
like this:

```
#mlb2-3734193 button.ml-subscribe-button {
       background: #47abd5;
        }
```

Comment: anytime available..!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the background-color property on the following class: .widget_circleicon-widget .circle-icon-box .circle-icon Then the background color of the book icon should change.

Comment: Can you elaborate better? I solved as suggested by Raimonds. Is your solution more appropriate?